# Is This Grammar SLR(1)?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar

I used [this tool](http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/start.html) to generate the SLR(1) parsing table for this LL(1)/LR(1) grammar (which generates a small subset of XML):

```
document ::= element EOF
element ::= < elementPrefix
elementPrefix ::= NAME attribute elementSuffix
attribute ::= NAME = STRING attribute
attribute ::= EPSILON
elementSuffix ::= > elementOrData endTag
elementSuffix ::= />
elementOrData ::= < elementPrefix elementOrData
elementOrData ::= DATA elementOrData
elementOrData ::= EPSILON
endTag ::= </ NAME >
```

The tool correctly generates the table and associated automaton, which suggests that the grammar is SLR(1). Is that really the case? I understand that every LR(0) grammar is also SLR(1), but I was not sure how that relates to LL(1)/LR(1) grammars.

Comment: You can use this (http://zaa.ch/jison/try/usf/) tool to see if your grammar is in SLR.

Answer (score 1):

LL(1) and SLR(1) are both subsets of LR(1). They don't have a simple relationship to each other.

Comment: So if a grammar is LR(1), it must necessarily be SLR(1)?

Comment: No I said that SLR(1) is a subset of LR(1). It's a proper subset, in fact.